# Download an xlrd book as an excel file throught a django view

Tags: django, xlrd

I need to download an excel file generated in memory using the xlrd library thought a django view as a direct download. I'm trying the following but I don't know how to convert the book object into something I can include in the HttpResponse

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from xlrd import Book

def my view:
   ...
   book: Book = <CREATED WITH XLRD>
   response = HttpResponse(book, content_type='application/ms-excel')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.xls"'
   return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is not tested. But normally, you will save your object into an io stream and then serve it with one of Django's responses:

```
import io
from xlrd import Book
from django.http import FileResponse


def my view:
    book: Book = <CREATED WITH XLRD>
    file = io.BytesIO()
    book.save(file)
    return FileResponse(file, as_attachment=True, filename="file.xls")
```